# Mock navigator object in React testing library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm using `navigator` to detect the camera settings in the browser. Below is excerpt from my React component.

```
  navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia({ video: true })
    .then(() => {
      setError(false);
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      if (e) {
        setError(true);
      }
    });
```

I have mocked the `navigator` object in my `setupTests.js` file

```
global.navigator.mediaDevices = {
  getUserMedia: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve()),
};
```

I would still get this error that says *'then' of* `undefined`. Could anyone please help?

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

      51 |   const [error, setError] = useState(false);
      52 |
    > 53 |   navigator.mediaDevices
         |   ^
      54 |     .getUserMedia({ video: true })
      55 |     .then(() => {
      56 |       setError(false);
```

Comment: Are you using CRA?

Comment: Yes @slideshowp2

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue myself. I had to create a mock file and import it in my test cases.

Created a mock file with the below code `__mocks__/navigator.js`

```js
const mockMediaDevices = {
  getUserMedia: jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce('fake data'),
};

Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'mediaDevices', {
  writable: true,
  value: mockMediaDevices,
});
```

In my test file, I imported the mock navigator file.

```js
import __mocks__/navigator';

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve();
  });
};

it('should test something', () => {  
   ...
})
```